# How to externalize links in a spring frame work

Tags: java, spring

I have to externalize a couple of links in my application. The links have to be in a properties file which can be changed without the need for a build and deploy. I tried adding values in the server.properties of my jboss and using that variable in my controller but i am unable to get a value.

How do i go about this?

Comment: [**Show us What have you tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 1):

Using [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("<myfile>");
String studentName = bundle.getString("<property-name>");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the values in *server.properties*, then configure `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in your *applicationContext*, something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <value>classpath:server.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

or the shorter Spring 3 version:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:server.properties"/>
```

and then just inject the values you need to your beans with

```
<bean id="someBean">
   <property name="myProperty" value="${this.is.property.from.server.properties}" />
</bean>
```

or with `@Value` annotation like

```
@Value("${this.is.property.from.server.properties}")
private String myProperty;
```

Comment: I think that the correct syntax would be `@Value("${some.property}")` (note the dollar sign).  I would also suggest using the `context` namespace since `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is outdated since Spring 3.1: `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:server.properties" />`

Comment: Just to clarify, `property-placeholder` is not only for Spring 3 (works at least as far back as Spring 2.5), but using it will make sure that the correct `Configurer` is used under the hood: `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for 3.0- or `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` for 3.1+.